# Loading bar with percentage in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to put together a loading screen, getting an animation to loop whilst the pages loads is no problem, but I would like to add both a visual of the percentage of the page loaded, and also pass the percentage as a prop to control an svg animation.

Most plugins/modules I've found have come up short.

Comment: look into this post [show percentage number in reactjs material ui progress bar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51254333/11310328)

Answer (score 0):

You can try `react-loadable`.

This is a docs: https://github.com/jamiebuilds/react-loadable.

Well, I using the `react-spinners` plugin for loading animation: https://www.davidhu.io/react-spinners/

```
import Loadable from 'react-loadable'
import ClipLoader from "react-spinners/ClipLoader"

const HotelDetail = Loadable({ 
  loader: () => import('path/to/ComponentPage'),
  loading: ClipLoader 
})
```