# Set Typography text color in Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm pretty new to Material UI, and I'm trying to set a `Typography` with a text color like this:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    text:{
      primary: "#FFFFFF"
    }
  }
});

const WhiteText = (props: { text:string, varient: Variant | 'inherit'}) => {
  return <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Typography variant={props.varient} align="center" color="textPrimary">{props.text}</Typography>
  </ThemeProvider>
}
...
<WhiteText varient="h3" text="This text should be white"/>
```

but the text will not change color :/

Am I applying the theme wrong?

Comment: The approach you used works fine for me here: https://codesandbox.io/s/white-text-qyli3

Comment: Hmm, there must be something I am missing in my larger program. Thanks!

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Though your approach works fine in [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/white-text-qyli3), it is not the approach I would recommend. Instead of nested themes, for customizations like this I would recommend using `withStyles` as shown below (for v4 of Material UI -- v5 example further down).

```
import React from "react";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";

const WhiteTextTypography = withStyles({
  root: {
    color: "#FFFFFF"
  }
})(Typography);

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App" style={{ backgroundColor: "black" }}>
      <WhiteTextTypography variant="h3">
        This text should be white
      </WhiteTextTypography>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit white text]

---

In v5, Material UI has enhanced the `color` prop significantly (for all components that have a `color` prop) to support any color in the theme's palette, so for white you can use [common.white](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/v5.0.3/packages/mui-material/src/styles/createPalette.js#L275):

```
import React from "react";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App" style={{ backgroundColor: "black" }}>
      <Typography variant="h3" color="common.white">
        This text should be white
      </Typography>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit white text]

Related answer: [Can you add an additional color in Material UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62408516/can-you-add-an-additional-color-in-material-ui/62455269#62455269)

Answer (score 54):

If you want to set a default color for all Typography elements, but not for other Material UI elements you can try this:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  typography: {
    allVariants: {
      color: "pink"
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: This is the answer! Thank you!!

Comment: I don't see this in the [theme explorer](https://material-ui.com/customization/default-theme/?expand-path=$.typography) How did you find this out?

Comment: This didn't work for me.  Anyone else have any luck?

Comment: In MUI v5, `createMuiTheme` is renamed to `createTheme`.

Comment: That also works for V5. Thank you

Comment: This worked for me in v5.  Huge time save, couldn't find this in the docs.

Answer (score 25):

The `color` prop of `Typography` is [theme aware](https://mui.com/system/the-sx-prop/#theme-aware-properties) which is a nice feature of [`sx` prop](https://mui.com/system/the-sx-prop/#main-content). This means besides setting the `color` as usual like this:

```
<Typography variant="h1" color="#00ff00">
```

You can reference the themed colors, either from the [default palette](https://mui.com/customization/default-theme/#main-content) or a [custom palette](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69264263/9449426) defined like below:

```
const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    tomato: '#FF6347',
    pink: {
      deep: '#FF1493',
      hot: '#FF69B4',
      medium: '#C71585',
      pale: '#DB7093',
      light: '#FFB6C1',
    },
  },
});
```

After registering the custom `theme` in `ThemeProvider`, you can use it in `Typography` by specifying the string path of the `Palette` object to the color value:

```
<Typography color="tomato">text</Typography>
<Typography color="pink.deep">text</Typography>
<Typography color="pink.hot">text</Typography>
<Typography color="pink.medium">text</Typography>
<Typography color="pink.pale">text</Typography>
<Typography color="pink.light">text</Typography>
```

Here is a couple of examples of `Typograhy` using the default colors from the palette:

```
<Typography color="primary.main">text</Typography>
<Typography color="primary.dark">text</Typography>
<Typography color="primary.light">text</Typography>
<Typography color="secondary">text</Typography>
<Typography color="text.secondary">text</Typography>
<Typography color="text.disabled">text</Typography>
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Answer (score 15):

If you don't want to use any themes. You can set it via `style` Attribute also.

```
<Typography style={{color:"#00adb5"}}  variant="h3" >My Text</Typography>
```

For MUI 5, use `sx` attribute,

```
<Typography sx={{ color: "#00adb5" }} variant="h3">
   My Text
</Typography>
```

Answer (score 8):

Set Typography Text Color in Material UI

```html
<Typography gutterBottom variant="h9" component="h2" color="secondary">
    {card.unitNumberList}
</Typography>
```

Answer (score 5):

I would try this - 
Include a typgraphy property in your theme, something like below with an 'h3' variant.

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    text: {
      primary: "#FFFFFF"
    }
  },

  typography: {
    useNextVariants: true,
    fontFamily: "Montserrat",
    h3: {
      fontSize: 33,
      fontFamily: "Montserrat",
      fontWeight: 300,
      color: "#2882F8",
      letterSpacing: "0.0075em",
      verticalAlign: "middle",
      alignItems: "center",
      textAlign: "center"
    }
  }
});
```

Then the color of your Typography should come directly from the variant="h3" that you just declared inside theme. You dont need to seperately pass the 'color' props to Typgraphy

For a working implementations of this, you can check [**this Repo**](https://github.com/rohan-paul/find-most-popular-github-user-in-your-city/tree/master/src) of mine, where I am keeping all my Typography variants in a single central global file called [**globalTheme.js**](https://github.com/rohan-paul/find-most-popular-github-user-in-your-city/blob/master/src/globalTheme.js) and in the App.js wrapping all the other components within MuiThemeProvider as below

```
<MuiThemeProvider theme={globalTheme}>
```

So all Typography component anywhere in the project will have access to the variants that I have declared in that globalTheme.js file.

Comment: No dice - I'm using material 4.9 so `MuiThemeProvider` -> `ThemeProvider` and there's no `useNextVariants`, but from what I can tell the theme isn't being applied at all. When I use `typography: {h3: {color: "#FFFFFF"}}` I also get no change in text color

Comment: I would definitely not recommend doing this. Material UI clearly separates palette (colors) from typography (font definitions). I don't think you'd want to mix them by defining color in the typography definition.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you need to define alternative colors for the text elements.

```
text: {
  primary: 'rgba(60, 72, 88, 1)',
  secondary: 'rgba(132, 146, 166, 1)',
  disabled: 'rgba(60, 72, 88, 0.38)',
  hint: 'rgba(60, 72, 88, 0.38)',
}
```

Then you can do the following:

```
<Typography variant="h1">Lorem ipsum</Typography> // Default text color
<Typography variant="subtitle1" color="textSecondary">dolor sit amet</Typography> // Secondary text color.
<Typography variant="body1" color="secondary">consectetur adipiscing elit</Typography> // Global secondary color.
```

Comment: How to make disabled color work?

<Typography variant="body1" color="textDisabled">example</Typography>

Not working for me

Comment: I found solution:

text: {
      primary: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)',
      secondary: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)',
    },
    textDisabled: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)',

Answer (score 1):

You can try using make styles from the material-ui core to create a custom look for your text which can include the text colour as shown in the example below

```
import {makeStyles} from '@material-ui/core/styles'

const useStyles=makeStyles((theme)=>({
text:{
    color:"#ffffff"
}
}));

const classes=useStyles();
<Typography align="center" className={classes.text}>This text should be white</Typography>
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who are still on v4, uses typescript and want to have a typesafe definition can extend mui's Typography like this:

```
import React, { FC } from "react";
import { createStyles, makeStyles, Theme } from "@material-ui/core";
import MuiTypography, { TypographyProps } from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import clsx from "clsx";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    warning: {
      color: theme.palette.warning.main,
    },
    success: {
      color: theme.palette.success.main,
    },
  })
);

type AdditionalColorKeys = keyof ReturnType<typeof useStyles>;

export type TypographyWithSpacingProps = Omit<TypographyProps, "color"> & {
  color?: AdditionalColorKeys | TypographyProps["color"];
};

export const Typography: FC<TypographyWithSpacingProps> = ({ color, className, ...props }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  let colorClass = "";

  if (color && color in classes) {
    colorClass = classes[color as keyof ReturnType<typeof useStyles>];
  }

  return <MuiTypography {...props} className={clsx(className, colorClass)} />;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also simply change the Typography's color by adding system props 'sx'
like this

```
<Typography
      variant="h6"
      sx={{
          color: "white",
         }}
>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this variant.

```json
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  typography: {
    text: {
        secondary: alpha("#13181F", 0.6)
    },
  },
});
```