# Passing custom palette colors to the color prop in MUI Typography

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, typography

I'm trying to pass a custom palette color into the `color` prop of a Typography tag.

I've got my theme set up in `theme.ts` like this:

```
declare module "@mui/material/styles" {
  interface Palette {
    tertiary: Palette['primary'];
  }
  interface PaletteOptions {
    tertiary: PaletteOptions['primary'];
  }
}

export const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: // not important
    secondary: //not important
    tertiary: {
      main: '#FFE461',
      dark: '#FED047',
      light: "#FFEC92"
    }
  }
});
```

Then I've got some code in my `index.tsx` file that looks like this:

```
import { CssBaseline, ThemeProvider, Typography } from "@mui/material";
import { theme } from "../theme/theme";

export function Index() {

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <CssBaseline/>
        <Typography variant="h1" component="h1" color="primary">Heading 1</Typography>
        <Typography variant="h2" component="h2" color="secondary">Heading 2</Typography>
        <Typography variant="h3" component="h3" color="tertiary">Heading 3</Typography>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

I am sure that the theme is applying because the colors for `primary` and `secondary` are both working as expected.  The third `<Typography>` tag's content is showing up as black, though, which is not what I'd expect.

I found a [YouTube tutorial](https://youtu.be/SUEkAOuQZTQ?t=933) that says that I can't pass my custom palette color into the `color` prop in the `<Typography>` tag and that I'd have to use the `sx` prop to pull in my custom color, but I'd rather avoid that if possible because it creates multiple different ways of setting the color on the `<Typography>` tag.  This is the initial setup for a new project, so I want to avoid that so other engineers working on it are encouraged to use a single code style.

Is there a way to have the Typography tag's `color` prop pick up custom palette colors?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set Typography text color in MUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60607586/set-typography-text-color-in-mui)

Comment: It does not.  I tried changing `color="tertiary"` to `color="common.tertiary"` and even `color="common.tertiary.main"` and it does not change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [Typography source code](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/v5.12.2/packages/mui-material/src/Typography/Typography.js#L77) you can find the following:

```
// TODO v6: deprecate these color values in v5.x and remove the transformation in v6
const colorTransformations = {
  primary: 'primary.main',
  textPrimary: 'text.primary',
  secondary: 'secondary.main',
  textSecondary: 'text.secondary',
  error: 'error.main',
};
```

You can see here that MUI is currently allowing `primary` as a shortcut for `primary.main` and similar for `secondary`, but it isn't doing that transformation for any additional colors you add. For anything else it will be looking in `theme.palette` for the exact path you specify for the `color` prop. Since `theme.palette.tertiary` points at an object rather than a valid color, it has no effect. As you already discovered, specifying `tertiary.main` does work.

Here's a full working example based on your code:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";
import CssBaseline from "@mui/material/CssBaseline";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";

declare module "@mui/material/styles" {
  interface Palette {
    tertiary: Palette["primary"];
  }
  interface PaletteOptions {
    tertiary: PaletteOptions["primary"];
  }
}

export const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    tertiary: {
      main: "#FFE461",
      dark: "#FED047",
      light: "#FFEC92"
    }
  }
});

export default function TypographyTheme() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <Typography variant="h1" component="h1" color="primary">
        Heading 1
      </Typography>
      <Typography variant="h2" component="h2" color="secondary">
        Heading 2
      </Typography>
      <Typography variant="h3" component="h3" color="tertiary.main">
        Heading 3
      </Typography>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Typography custom color]

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I need to pass in `color="tertiary.main"`, not just `color="tertiary"`.

Comment: The duplicate was correct.

Comment: @Arkellys The duplicate was related, but the point of confusion here was a little different as far as why colors added with the exact same structure as `primary` and `secondary` don't work the same for the `color` prop and MUI isn't consistent. For instance `color="tertiary"` would work fine on a `Button`.